# How can I use grep to get all files and words in each file which contains the suffix (ASC. or DEFG. or CDW.)

Tags: unix, sas

At the moment with `- grep -row "ASC.*\| DEFG.*\|"`
I get below result:

```
/data/de_pgms/programs/00_individuals/programs/parts:ASC */
/data/de_pgms/programs/00_individuals/programs/parts:ASC.LKP_DAILY_DATES
/data/de_pgms/programs/00_individuals/programs/parts:DEFG Analysts\DATA_REQUEST.XLSX";
/data/de_pgms/programs/00_individuals/programs/parts:DEFG_AA/Constrained Supplier List";
```

How do i make sure I only get results such as

```
/data/de_pgms/programs/00_individuals/programs/parts:ASC.LKP_DAILY_DATES
/data/de_pgms/programs/00_individuals/programs/acm:DEFG.EDS_MONTHLY_RUN
```

**Question**: 
how can I use grep to get all files and words in each file which contain the suffix ASC. or DEFG. or CDW.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -e ":ASC\..*$\|:DEFG\..*$" file
```

Try this. It changes your pattern to a regular expression adding more context. most of it is literal like your expression however the $ at the end being an important feature to say the line ends here. prepending the ":" to the expressions prevents some false matches too. finally the .* says to match any one or more of any character.

Comment: Thanks Gary. grep -row "ASC\..*$\|DEFG\..*$" file, did what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks also to you I learned the -row feature. very handy. It returns only exactly the matching part of the line, not the entire line.